# Trouble with UISearchBar implementation in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

So I am messing around with user queries using Parse. I have a table view as my data source within a UIViewController, and I am using an extension on it like so

```
extension addFriend: UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate {

    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        print("worked")
    }

    func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        print("editing")
        searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(true, animated: true)
        state = .SearchState
    }  

    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
        searchBar.text = ""
        searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(false, animated: true)
        state = .DefaultState
    }

    func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        Reachability.searchUsers(searchText, block: updateList)
    }

}
```

specifically for my search bar declared as

```
@IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
```

Reachability is a public class with my query functions e.g. searchUsers().

I am using a model described here
https://www.makeschool.com/tutorials/build-a-photo-sharing-app-part-2/friend-search-follow
but for some reason the search bar is not working. The print statements are there to verify this fact, and I have tried adopting the search bar delegates at class declaration and typing search bar functions within the class as I had written similar code not long before I tried this. It is not working and I can't exactly figure out why. I have done exactly this before and it worked just fine. I am new to swift programming, is there something I am missing? I would appreciate any help or shove in the right direction. Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you implemented and given `UISearchBar` delegate

Comment: yep ok that worked.. I just forgot to uncomment that line in my viewDidLoad. Oops. THANKS A LOT!